# Summarise values dplyr r

Tags: r, dplyr, quartile

I have a target variable ranging from -33 to 17 and the variable merchant_category_id that has int type.

```
summary(total_trans$target)
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
-33.21928  -0.80808  -0.09018  -0.45554   0.54223  17.96507 

str(total_trans$merchant_category_id)
merchant_category_id: int  278 307 705 307 705 307 705 307 278 332
```

I want to find the quantity, from lowest to highest, of the variable merchant_category_id, only when the target variable is less than or equal to the first quartile.

I tried to do this:

```
total_trans %>% group_by(merchant_category_id) %>% summarise(counting = count(merchant_category_id))
```

Response is an error:

```
Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error
```

After:

```
total_trans %>% summarise(Range = list(range(merchant_category_id[target <= summary(target)[2]])))
```

Response:

```
    Range
1 -1, 891
```

Also try:

```
total_trans %>% group_by(merchant_category_id) %>% summarise(Range = list(range(target[target < -0.80808])))
```

Response:

```
# A tibble: 325 x 2
   merchant_category_id Range    
                  <int> <list>   
 1                   -1 <dbl [2]>
 2                    2 <dbl [2]>
 3                    9 <dbl [2]>
 4                   11 <dbl [2]>
 5                   14 <dbl [2]>
 6                   16 <dbl [2]>
 7                   18 <dbl [2]>
 8                   19 <dbl [2]>
 9                   21 <dbl [2]>
10                   27 <dbl [2]>
# ... with 315 more rows
There were 26 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

If I do this

```
total_trans %>% count(merchant_category_id, wt = target < -0.80808)
```

or

```
total_trans %>%
  mutate(q1 = target <= quantile(target, 1/4)) %>%
  filter(q1) %>%
  group_by(merchant_category_id) %>%
  summarise(count = n())
```

I get this in response:

```
   merchant_category_id     n
                  <int> <int>
 1                   -1   432
 2                    2  8364
 3                    9  2580
 4                   11     9
 5                   14  1800
 6                   16   177
 7                   18     4
 8                   19 24371
 9                   21   466
10                   27     4
```

This is almost what I need. It is only necessary to order column n, from the largest quantity to the smallest quantity

How to use dplyr to do this?

Comment: Try `library(dplyr); total_trans %>% summarise(Range = list(range(merchant_category_id[target <= summary(target)[2]])))` or use `quantile(target)[2]` instead of `summary`

Comment: This did not work:

Comment: ok, any reasons/errors  that you want to share.  Otherwise `did not work` can mean a lot of things

Comment: This line did not return quantities by category

Comment: Did you meant grouped by 'merchant_category_id`  In that case, `total_trans %>% group_by(merchant_category_id) %>% summarise(Range = list(range(target[target <= quantile(target)[2]])))`

Comment: Almost that. Only it returns the values ​​in ascending order. My intention is the categories of greater quantity for those of smaller quantity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know it this is best answer:

```
top_n(total_trans %>%
  mutate(q1 = target <= quantile(target, 1/4)) %>%
  filter(q1) %>%
  group_by(merchant_category_id) %>%
  summarise(count = n())%>% arrange(desc(count)), 20)
```

But works using top_n.

Thank you very much everybody!!!!

Answer (score 0):

For what I understand of the question something like the following will do it.

First make up a dataset.

```
set.seed(1234)
n <- 100
total_trans <- data.frame(merchant_category_id = sample.int(20, n, TRUE),
                          target = runif(n, -33, 17))
```

Now the problem.

```
library(dplyr)

total_trans %>%
  mutate(q1 = target <= quantile(target, 1/4)) %>%
  filter(q1) %>%
  group_by(merchant_category_id) %>%
  summarise(count = n())
```

Note that the two code lines `mutate` and `filter` can become just one: `filter(target <= quantile(target, 1/4))`. I have left it like that to make the code more readable.

**Edit.**

The following sorts by count and keeps only the first 20 rows of the result.

```
total_trans %>%
  filter(target <= quantile(target, 1/4)) %>%
  count(merchant_category_id) %>%
  arrange(desc(n)) %>%
  head(20)
```

Comment: This did not work because the data was not returned sorted (categories with more quantity up categories with less quantity). I got this same result doing: [link]total_trans%>% count (merchant_category_id, wt = target <-0.80808)[/link]

Comment: @Ângelo In the original question you did not ask to sort by count. And you now also keep only the first 20. See the edit.